# Substitute the referenced value in Table Mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

This works as expected. But as soon as I change the % in "schema-name" parameter to a reference, it fails.

```
  DMSTaskMigration:
    Type: 'AWS::DMS::ReplicationTask'
    Properties:
      ReplicationInstanceArn: !Ref DMSReplicationInstance
      SourceEndpointArn: !Ref DMSSourceEndpoint
      TargetEndpointArn: !Ref DMSTargetEndpoint
      MigrationType: full-load
      TableMappings: >-
        {"rules": [{"rule-type": "selection", "rule-id": "1", "rule-action":
        "include", "object-locator": {"schema-name": "%", "table-name": "%"},
        "rule-name": "1"}]}
      Tags: 
        - 
          Key: myString
          Value: someString
```

The user should provide the value of schema name. I guess I should use !sub but not sure about the syntax. The following code does not work.

```
  DMSTaskMigration:
    Type: 'AWS::DMS::ReplicationTask'
    Properties:
      ReplicationInstanceArn: !Ref DMSReplicationInstance
      SourceEndpointArn: !Ref DMSSourceEndpoint
      TargetEndpointArn: !Ref DMSTargetEndpoint
      MigrationType: full-load
      TableMappings: >-
        {"rules": [{"rule-type": "selection", "rule-id": "1", "rule-action":
        "include", "object-locator": {"schema-name": !Ref MySql5Database, "table-name": "%"},
        "rule-name": "1"}]}
      Tags: 
        - 
          Key: myString
          Value: someString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `Sub`, you could do the following:

```
  DMSTaskMigration:
    Type: 'AWS::DMS::ReplicationTask'
    Properties:
      ReplicationInstanceArn: !Ref DMSReplicationInstance
      SourceEndpointArn: !Ref DMSSourceEndpoint
      TargetEndpointArn: !Ref DMSTargetEndpoint
      MigrationType: full-load
      TableMappings: !Sub >-
        {"rules": [{"rule-type": "selection", "rule-id": "1", "rule-action":
        "include", "object-locator": {"schema-name": "${MySql5Database}", "table-name": "%"},
        "rule-name": "1"}]}
      Tags: 
        - 
          Key: myString
          Value: someString
```